# Downloading JavaScript Bundle 100.00%

Tags: react-native

when i was enable debug remote JS in App Developer Menu(React-Native). Expo app is Stucked it showing Downloading JavaScript Bundle 100.00%

Comment: Better we can use **react-native init Sample** this is one no need expo app.Its working debug option..

Answer (score 9):

Having the same problem, what helped me was going to the Expo menu (e.g., by shaking the phone on iOS), and there chose the "Debug Remote JS" and then going to the Expo menu again, and chose "Stop Remote Debugging".

After doing this cycle once (or maybe twice) the app was loaded. Hope this helps!

The Expo sdk version is 28.0.0 and client version is 2.7.0.1016186.

Comment: This is a very subtle gotcha. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered this issue and what i've done is

- Open Recent apps
- close expo app
- open expo app
- open your project

In my case it worked