# Expo App stops after Javascript bundle 100%

Tags: react-native, expo

When a react native app is run on expo app on an android device, expo app stops and starts to bundle again when javascript is bundled 100%. I am unable to run my app. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting the app worked for me, make sure that you clear the app from Recent apps before restart.

You can find the full discussion here.
[Downloading JavaScript Bundle 100.00%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48761817/downloading-javascript-bundle-100-00?rq=1)